# How to set a specific theme in jQuery week calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How to set a specific theme in jQuery week calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#switcher').themeswitcher(
            {loadTheme:'Dark Hive',
            cookieName: 'Dark Hive'});
          });
```

html

```
<div id="switcher" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/

Doesn't look like it has "themes" per-say, more so you'd have to make the css/etc changes yourself.

`"I have entertained the thought of making the calendar jquery-ui theme compatible but I don’t think the design elements in the calendar completely fit with those provided by the theme builder so probably wouldn’t work out."`

Comment: If you download jquery-week-calendar and see full demo You will find that there is one calender example with theme switcher. using that we can select any of the theme given.But I am just not getting how to use a specific theme.